Is Vegeta stronger than Goku in Dragon Ball Daima, since he was stronger than him when younger?
Supposedly Vegeta is some years older than Goku. When he was young, Vegeta was stronger than Goku, being capable of killing several Saibaimen with power level of 1,200 at the same time. So when Vegeta was a teenager or kid, he was stronger than 1,200. However when Goku was a teenager or a kid , his power level was between 10 to 260.
How does this work now that they've been turned into children? Is Vegeta still physically older than Goku? Goku was somehow able to retain his super saiyan transformation, does this mean his power now is not related at all to the power he had when he was a real kid?
Is Vegeta stronger than Goku in Dragon Ball Daima, since he was stronger than him when younger?

First, regardless of their birth dates (Goku was born as planet Vegeta was destroyed while Vegeta is a few years older), the wish in Daima was extremely clear: they will turn into the age of first graders (about 6). So they are precisely the same age in Daima, physically. Second, oddly enough, this is not the first time a Shenron de-aged characters (King Piccolo returned to his young and Pilaf were turned to children) and in particular isn't not even the first time Shenron turned Goku into a kid again. As we saw in GT, turning Goku into a child did make it more difficult for him to fight, as he was an adult much longer than he was a child, but it did not make him less of a threat. In GT, Goku as a child was still the strongest in the universe so the first villain had to resort to stealing a body to compete.
That said, the size of his body or age of his body for that matter, doesn't necessarily make him weaker. Gohan in particular was a very strong child, stronger than when he was 7 years later. Similarly, King Piccolo would not have made a wish to restore his youth if his strength only moved in one direction. In the opening saga of Dragonball Super, when Goku transformed into a Super Saiyan God, he also reverted to a younger version of himself (although the explanation leaves much to be desired and I would not look to DBS for consistency).
However just from GT, you can infer that Goku's power is unrelated to his power at that age, likely because his ki level differs from even he was a child and that it's the main driver of power level, as opposed to say muscle mass. I suspect Vegeta to undergo the same reasoning so it's safe to say that he's not stronger than Goku in Daima.
As an aside, there are inconsistencies with Shenron's wish. Piccolo in particular was very clearly already much larger than his miniature form when he was 6, which is after the events of Dragonball, when he was full sized. Dende is also about the age of Gohan, who is nearly an adult during the time of Daima and should not be an infant. Gohan of course is absent, but likely purposely so: Gohan was extremely powerful when he was a child, much more powerful than when he fought Dabura, which would make him stronger than everyone in the Demon realm if the power scaling had worked as you described.
